# How can we create Azure's Data Factory pipeline with Cosoms DB (with Graph API) as data sink ?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-cosmosdb

How can we create Azure's Data Factory pipeline with Cosoms DB (with Graph API) as data sink ? (data source being Cosmos DB only (Document DB as API)

Answer (score 2):

One option that is available to you is to simply continue using the Document API for the graph enabled CosmosDB sink. If you transform and write your documents into the destination in GraphSON format as regular documents they will be automatically usable as vertices and edges in future graph traversals.

The ability to use both DocumentSQL and Gremlin APIs against the same collection is one of the most exciting and powerful features of CosmosDB IMO (and the team plans to support more APIs interacting with the same dataset in the future).

Not only is this possible, but I've personally observed significant improvements in throughput when importing large datasets into a graph enabled Cosmos collection using the Document APIs instead of gremlin. I plan to release a blog post describing this process in more detail in the near future.

Answer (score 1):

Cosmos DB Graph API is not supported yet and we will add to our product backlog.