# Azure Data Factory and GraphDb

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-data-factory

In the Azure environment, I have an Azure SQL Db and a CosmosDb Graph. Using an Azure Data Factory, I
need to insert/update data from the Sql db to the GraphDb.

My thinking is that I need to first transform the data to json and from there insert it into the GraphDb.
Is this the way to go? Are there any other ways?

Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44143557/how-can-we-create-azures-data-factory-pipeline-with-cosoms-db-with-graph-api

Comment: So it seems nothing changed from 2017. Thank you for the link @silent.

Comment: Yes, it does, thank you. So your suggestion is to use a bulk insert. I was thinking of also using the SQL API, since it works on the graphdb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.Based on the [ADF copy activity connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview) and the thread: [How can we create Azure's Data Factory pipeline with Cosoms DB (with Graph API) as data sink ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44143557/how-can-we-create-azures-data-factory-pipeline-with-cosoms-db-with-graph-api) mentioned by @silent,Cosmos db graph api connector is not supported in ADF so far. You could vote up this feature in this feedback [link](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory/suggestions/37339906-we-do-a-lot-of-work-in-the-gremlin-api-and-would-l) which is updated at April 12, 2019.

2.Cosmos db migration tool isn't a supported import tool for Gremlin API accounts at this time. Please see this link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/import-data

3.You could get an idea of [graph bulk executor .NET library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/bulk-executor-graph-dotnet) now.This is the sample application:git clone https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-cosmosdb-graph-bulkexecutor-dotnet-getting-started.gi

Comment: How would you suggest I integrate the bulk executor in the data factory, through an Azure function?

Comment: @MariusB. Yes,the bulk connector is just usage of sdk which could be done anywhere. Surely,you could invoke it in azure function activity. Any issues, you could post here and i will help you.

Comment: I see there are two options : 1. To use the bulk executor you suggested or 2. to use the SQL API(since it also works on the graphdb). Do you save any insights about pros/cons(speed/cost and so on)?

Comment: @MariusB. i have no idea about sql api works on the graphdb, sql api and graph api are different in cosmos db,aren't them? Any links i need to sync?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47045818/cosmosdb-creation-api-option-sql-vs-graph , this seems to be one of them, I also saw this on other sources.

Comment: Just made a small test, and managed to insert data from the SQL Db into the CosmodDb graph with SQL API.

Comment: @MariusB. Any issues?

Comment: No issues,maybe I'm wrong, but I think SQL API is suited only for simple scenarios( when gettings data from SQL Db to GraphDb).

Comment: @MariusB. Agreed, graph db must be better supported by graph API.